# Issues when using WSAAddressToString

Tags: c++, winapi, wsastartup

**QUESTION :** I'm trying to use **WSAAddressToString** function to get the ip address of the computer .I went through the msdn documentation in their website  and there are too many structures within structures and   i feel that's the place where i'm going wrong . The code is provided in the  [pastebin link here](http://pastebin.com/G4qMWQPy) . Please let me know where exactly I'm going wrong.

**ANSWER** : The issue is fixed after including **WSAStartup** function in the code and some modifications in the existing code . The complete code is in the pastebin and the modified section is below .

```
     retval = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
      if (retval != 0)
      {
          printf("WSAStartup() failed with error code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
      }
   else
       printf("WSAStartup() is OK...\n");


        size=256;

        lp=pAddresses->FirstUnicastAddress->Address.lpSockaddr;
        size2=pAddresses->FirstUnicastAddress->Address.iSockaddrLength;
        if(WSAAddressToStringA(lp,size2,NULL,op,&size)!= 0)
        {
                    printf("This thing has failed \n");
                    printf("errordetail: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());

                    return 1;
        }
        else
                    printf("\t The ip address is  = %s\n", op);
```

Comment: Even better, tell us what happens that should not happen, and what does not happen that should happen.

Comment: The function call is failing that's what is happening now and i refered the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741516%28v=VS.85%29.aspx for the function .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please change this:

```
if(WSAAddressToString(lp,size2, NULL,op,&size) != 0) {
    printf("This thing has failed \n");   
    return 1;
} else
    printf("Address string = %s\n", op);
    pAddresses = pAddresses->Next;
}
```

To this:

```
long errorcode = WSAAddressToString(lp,size2, NULL,op,&size);
if(errorcode != 0) {
    printf("The error is number: %i\n", errorcode);   
    return 1;
} else
    printf("Address string = %s\n", op);
    pAddresses = pAddresses->Next;
}
```

Then tell us what number it printed.

Or look it up in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**EDIT:**

```
SOCKADDR_IN6 addrTemp;
addrTemp.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
long errorcode = WSAAddressToString(&addrTemp,size2, NULL,op,&size);
if(errorcode != 0) {
    //printf("The error is number: %i\n", errorcode);   
    printf("errordetail: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
} else
    printf("Address string = %s\n", op);
    pAddresses = pAddresses->Next;
}
```

Comment: its giving me -1 . had done that before but forgot to edit the code in the pastebin.

Comment: Ok, then please printf("errordetail: %i\n", WSAGetLastError()) instead of the printf which i wrote above.

Comment: Its WSAEFAULT, i seem to be going wrong with the pointers part i believe.

Comment: Ok. Try having top level `SOCKADDR_IN6 addrTemp;` and passing `&addrTemp` as first parameter to WSAAddressToString.

Comment: And also set `addrTemp.sin6_family = AF_INET6`.

Comment: I didn't understand the solution , could you edit and paste the code in answer section ,please bear with me .

Comment: Done. We are getting closer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32617/discussion-between-santhosh-pai-and-eznme)

Comment: +1 for the effort you went to debugging and helping the OP get the info they needed.  OP, you can learn something about basic debugging and error-checking from this :)